# How to fix shifter returning to 6th gear

Tags: shifter

I need help I was riding my Roadmaster Granite Peak bike when suddenly the gear shifter just shot into 6th Gear and will no longer lock into other gears for you to have it stay in a gear like 2nd or 3rd you have to hold it in that position otherwise it'll shoot back into 6th gear anyone know what the problem could be and how to fix it[image][image]

Comment: Sounds like the shifter is not holding tension on the inner cable any more.  Is it a "revoshift" ?

Comment: I took the shifter apart and figured it out the metal spring that latches into each Notch to keep it in gear one of the plastic pieces on the side that holds it in place  snapped off

Comment: Sounds like it might not last very long when repaired.  You might be best off getting a pod/trigger shifter instead.

Comment: Can I do that with my bike because it's in 18 speed six gears on the wheel three on the pedals and the shifter that controls the three on the pedals is weird I have updated the question with a photo of the shifters and the bike

Comment: @kevpar did you find a replacement shifter that works? I have the same bike and my shifters are jammed in a specific gear. I need to swap those out but not sure with what since I can't find "TD One" replacement parts anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

There is no noticable difference, most Roadmaster/puh-cific made bicycles will interchange shifter/derailleur parts, due to the fact that they are all using the lowest quality Shimano products. If you find a shifter with more advertised speeds, then lock the lower ones out at the derailleur setting( the two screws)